# How to prove excluded middle is irrefutable in Coq?

Tags: logic, coq, coq-tactic

I was trying to prove the following simple theorem from [an online course](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/Logic.html) that excluded middle is irrefutable, but got stuck pretty much at step 1:

```
Theorem excluded_middle_irrefutable: forall (P:Prop), ~~(P \/ ~ P).
Proof.
  intros P. unfold not. intros H.
```

Now I get:

```
1 subgoals
P : Prop
H : P \/ (P -> False) -> False
______________________________________(1/1)
False
```

If I `apply H`, then the goal would be `P \/ ~P`, which is excluded middle and can't be proven constructively. But other than `apply`, I don't know what can be done about the hypothesis `P \/ (P -> False) -> False`: implication `->` is primitive, and I don't know how to `destruct` or decompose it. And this is the only hypothesis.

My question is, how can this be proven using only primitive tactics ([as characterized here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682544/is-there-a-minimal-complete-set-of-tactics-in-coq), i.e. no mysterious `auto`s)?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps looking at the proof term (created with `tauto` and some simplification) makes some sense: `Check
  fun (P : Prop) (H : ~ (P \/ ~ P)) =>
    False_ind False (H (or_intror (fun H0 => H (or_introl H0)))).`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not an expert on this subject, but it was recently discussed on the [Coq mailing-list](http://coq-club.inria.narkive.com/jqsPmOBk/is-a-prop-a-a-provable-in-coq). I'll summarize the conclusion from this thread. If you want to understand these kinds of problems more thoroughly, you should look at [double-negation translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-negation_translation).

The problem falls within intuitionistic propositional calculus and can thus be decided by [`tauto`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic146).

```
Theorem excluded_middle_irrefutable: forall (P:Prop), ~~(P \/ ~ P).
  tauto.
Qed.
```

The thread also provides a more elaborate proof. I'll attempt to explain how I would have come up with this proof. Note that it's usually easier for me to deal with the programming language interpretation of lemmas, so that's what I'll do:

```
Theorem excluded_middle_irrefutable: forall (P:Prop), ~~(P \/ ~ P).
  unfold not.
  intros P f.
```

We are asked to write a function that takes the function `f` and produces a value of type `False`. The only way to get to `False` at this point is to invoke the function `f`.

```
 apply f.
```

Consequently, we are asked to provide the arguments to the function `f`. We have two choices, either pass `P` or `P -> False`. I don't see a way to construct a `P` so I'm choosing the second option.

```
  right.
  intro p.
```

We are back at square one, except that we now have a `p` to work with!
So we apply `f` because that's the only thing we can do.

```
  apply f.
```

And again, we are asked to provide the argument to `f`. This is easy now though, because we have a `p` to work with.

```
  left.
  apply p.
Qed.
```

The thread also mentions a proof that is based on some easier lemmas. The first lemma is `~(P /\ ~P)`.

```
Lemma lma (P:Prop) : ~(P /\ ~P).
  unfold not.
  intros H.
  destruct H as [p].
  apply H.
  apply p.
Qed.
```

The second lemma is `~(P \/ Q) -> ~P /\ ~Q`:

```
Lemma lma' (P Q:Prop) : ~(P \/ Q) -> ~P /\ ~Q.
  unfold not.
  intros H.
  constructor.
  - intro p.
    apply H.
    left.
    apply p.
  - intro q.
    apply H.
    right.
    apply q.
Qed.
```

These lemmas suffice to the show:

```
Theorem excluded_middle_irrefutable: forall (P:Prop), ~~(P \/ ~ P).
  intros P H.
  apply lma' in H.
  apply lma in H.
  apply H.
Qed.
```

Comment: +1Thanks for the pointer. This works as advertised. But it's still mysterious as the mailing list said. (The interpretation in the mailing list is written with non-English characters, and the math part is really difficult to read). Any chance you could add interpretation of the big picture in English?