# Why would the tactic 'exact' be complete for Coq proofs?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

In the question [Is there a minimal complete set of tactics in Coq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682544/is-there-a-minimal-complete-set-of-tactics-in-coq), the answers mentioned that `exact` would be enough to prove all goals. Could someone explain and give an example? For example, how would the goal `A \/ B -> B \/ A` with A, B being Prop be proven by merely a bunch of `exact`? If you have other better examples, please don't hesitate to answer as well. The point is to give some explanation on this issue and give a non-trivial example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recall that proofs in Coq are just terms in the (lambda) Calculus of Inductive Constructions. Thus, your lemma is proven as:

```
Lemma test A B : A \/ B -> B \/ A.
Proof.
exact (fun x => match x with
  | or_introl p => or_intror p
  | or_intror p => or_introl p
  end).
Qed.
```

which is almost the same as:

```
Definition test' A B : A \/ B -> B \/ A :=
fun x => match x with
  | or_introl p => or_intror p
  | or_intror p => or_introl p
  end.
```

[they differ in "opacity", don't worry about that, but Coq 8.8 will likely support the `Lemma foo := term` syntax, closer to `exact term`.]

A more convenient tactic to build proofs is `refine`, which allows you to specify partial terms:

```
Lemma test'' A B : A \/ B -> B \/ A.
Proof.
refine (fun x => _).
refine (match x with | or_introl _ => _ | or_intror _ => _ end).
+ refine (or_intror a).
+ refine (or_introl b).
Qed.
```

In fact, `refine` is the basic tactic of the Coq proof engine; `exact T` basically executes `refine T` and checks that no goals remain open.

Answer (score 3):

Because of its theoretical foundations, the logic of Coq does not rely on tactics as a primitive way to construct proofs.  In fact, you could use Coq and construct what would be considered as legitimate proofs without ever using any tactic by using the idiom.

```
Lemma test3 A B : A \/ B -> B \/ A.
Proof 
 fun x => match x with
    or_introl p => or_intror p 
                  | or_introl p => or_introl p
 end.
```

So the question of "complete set of tactics" is not completely meaningful.

On the other hand, tactics have been introduced to make the work easier.  So it is useful to know a *reasonably complete set of tactics* that makes it possible to perform proofs without having a thorough knowledge of Coq's theoretical foundations.  My favorite set of tactics is:

- `intros`, `apply` (to deal with universal quantification and implication);
- `destruct` (to deal with logical connectives `and`, also written `/\` and `or`, also written `\/`, and existential quantification, when in hypotheses);
- `split` to deal with `and` when in a goal's conclusion;
- `left`, `right` to deal with `or` when in a goal's conclusion.
- `exists` to deal with an existential quantification when in the conclusion,
- `assert` to establish intermediate facts (not needed for completeness, but it really helps you write more readable proofs),
- `exact` and `assumption` when what you want to prove is really obvious from the context.

When reasoning about natural numbers, you will undoubtedly define functions by pattern-matching and recursively and reason about their behavior, so it is important to also know the tactics `change`, `simpl`, `case`, `case_eq`, `injection`, and `discriminate`  Last, when you start making proofs that are advanced enough you need tools for automated proofs like `ring` and `lia`.